# PHP or operator similar to javascript? Is there a simple way?

Tags: php

In javascript I can pass an object literal to an object as a parameter and if a value does not exist I can refer to a default value by coding the following;

```
this.title = params.title || false;
```

Is there a similar way to do this with PHP?

I am new to PHP and I can't seem to find an answer and if there is not an easy solution like javascript has, it seems pure crazy to me!!

Is the best way in PHP to use a ternary operator with a function call?

```
isset($params['title']) ? $params['title'] : false;
```

Thanks

Comment: **`Ternary` is the best way.** No such functionality in PHP. It's another one of those unnatural `JS` things...

Comment: @Code "Unnatural"? Really?

Comment: @deceze Yes because `||` *(aka `OR`)* should be a `bool`. [Like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction). It is in `C/C++`, where real programming happens.

Comment: @Code Seriously? "Real" programming? Dude, *embrace* different languages. JS's `||` is a very interesting operator which enables very interesting code; it's not any less "real" than a traditional boolean `||`.

Comment: @deceze couldn't agree more each language has its downfalls and good points `||` in javascript is very nice!

Comment: @deceze There's `scripting` *(interpreted)* and than there's `programming` *(compiled)*. `||` is not interesting... it's just CONFUSING! *Like steering wheel on the right when everyone else has it on the left.* (I embrace many languages but I know when I'm scripting or programming.)

Comment: @CodeAngry My favourite language is javascript, you know why you can script in it as you say, and create so much much more better stuff in 5 minutes than you ever could with c/c++, plus it is fun

Comment: @Code You really have a weird idea of what distinguishes "real" programming... You're an *Uphill in the snow, both ways* guy, eh?

Comment: @deceze +1 for last comment. I LIKE it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't look for an *exact equivalent*, because PHP's boolean operators and array access mechanism are just too different to provide that. What you want is to provide *default values* for an argument:

```
function foo(array $params) {
    $params += array('title' => false, ...);

    echo $params['title'];
}
```

Comment: No it does not, that's the point: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Comment: I keep staring and I don't see the default argument value in your example function :) You're just enforcing the argument type and prefilling the array. That's not really how default arguments work.

Comment: @Code You seem to be very hung up on one specific way to do things. Do you have a better suggestion for establishing default array values?

Comment: @deceze haha, just to clarify if title is set, adding the existing title does nothing, if it is not set then it gets assigned? Thanks

Comment: @deceze I would use explicit arguments, not arrays. And default their values. This is the WordPress way of doing things. Stick all arguments in an array so you need to LEARN or SEEK them all before using a function. When you could break them nicely apart in as arguments or an object properties and that allows friendly code completion too. I'm hung on reusability and IDE code completion friendliness.

Comment: @Code I'm actually totally on board with that. Passing arbitrary unstructured arrays is not good overall. That doesn't mean it doesn't have its place in some situations. Without knowing more about what the OP wants to use this for, I won't comment on whether this is the best method to use this or not.

Comment: I have an object that can take multiple parameters that may or may not be defined. It may be my bad code structure but in javascript I can overcome the problem, as I am fairly new to php I either need to as @deceze suggested or rethink my code structure

Answer (score 2):

somethig like this `$title = (isset($title) && $title !== '') ? $title : false;`

Answer (score 1):

Or using the `empty` function:

```
empty($params['title']) ? false : $params['title'];
```

Answer (score 0):

$x = ($myvalue == 99) ? "x is 99": "x is not 99";

PHP one liner if ... 
    if ($myvalue == 99) {x is 99} else {x is not 99 //set value to false here}

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class MyObject {
    // Default value of object property
    public $_title = null;
    // Default value of argument (constructor)
    public function __construct($title = null){
        $this->_title = $title;
    }
    // Default value of argument (setter)
    public function setTitle($title = null){
        // Always validate arguments if you're serious about what you're doing
        if(!is_null($title) and !is_string($title)){
            trigger_error('$title should be a null or a string.', E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        $this->_title = $title;
        return true;
    }
} // class MyObject;
?>
```

**This is how you do an object with default values.** *3 ways in 1.* You either default the property value in the class definition. Or you default it on the `__construct` assignment or in a specific setter `setTitle`.

*But it all depends on the rest of your code.* You need to forget `JS` in order to properly use `PHP`. This is a slightly stricter programming environment, even if very loose-typed. We have real classes in `PHP`, not *imaginary function classes elephants* that offer no IDE code-completion support like in `JS`.

Comment: Although I agree, I think classes defer from true programming. True prototypal inheritance is alot cleaner, efficient, and more true. Prototypal inheritance enforces a `has a` relationship, rather classes that extend multiple classes and enforce a `is a` relationship, when we all know that some classes should extend another one because they do not have that `has a` relationship.

Comment: @GriffLab **I think classes defer from true programming** - *this made my day*. Spoken like a true `C` coder. You're really missing out... `Classes` = `procedures` + `structures` of `C` made whole again. Plus you have the beautiful `destructor` where you can clean things up and not have to track it everywhere. In C++ you also have the template classes which blow anyone's mind in terms of code reusability. I'm not an `objectualize all things` maniac but I know the benefits of a class/object. *I did start out in C, 1.5 decades ago...*